# Looking for a good idea and a good Ruby structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am writing a Rake task to populate a database for development purposes to have some data to work with. ( but In test I am using FactoryGirl, so not talking about that. )

So let's say I have two sample Organizations in my demo database, so I have defined them like this:

```
sample_organizations = [ '37 Signals', 'Fog Creek']
```

and then a small method to populate the DB like this:

```
def create_organizations
  sample_organization.each { |item|
    Organization.first_or_create(
        name: item,
        time_zone: 'Central'
    )
  }
end
```

so the good thing is that two months from now if I wanted to add a third organization I just go to top of my code and hand type another organization name in that array. Method still works and creates it.

**Now here starts the question:** I have more tables to populate! For example **Summaries** table which is hanging off of Organization table, so each organization can have many Summaries, so we have an `organization_id foreign key` in Summary table to fill too.
But still I want to have a method like `create_summaries` that does something similar to `create_organization` method above, but this time fills in Summaries table, and the tricky part is to fill in that organization_id field of the table.

How should I approach this? 
Let's say Summaries table has these fields:  `id (auto generate by Rails) , organization_id, name, member_count`

Answer (score 1):

Try using Populator gem for tasks like this. It is easy to use, and you can generate complex structures. [Screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/126-populating-a-database).

As you can't use those, use select a random parent object, or specify one by name in a hash.

```
summaries = [{:name => "foo", :organization => "bar"}]
```

Comment: thanks but for the reasons and long discussions that "people better than me!"  had at work, they told the team not to use Faker and Populator!  I don't know why but if I do it, it won't pass code review! :(

Comment: Why don't you ask them for advice if they know the reason?