# What is the Ruby Structure to model a One-to-Many table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an `Organization` table with fields like:

```
id
name
time_zone
```

and then I have a couple of other tables like `Doctors` with fields like:

```
id
organization_id  #foreign_key to Organization
name
salary
```

How can I model this with Ruby? Is it with Arrays? Hashes? Maps?

I am not very familiar with Ruby yet so not sure what do we have for this in Ruby?
For example if it was flat, I could maybe use a simple array, but how about this structure?
I want to be able to access and loop through the hierarchy later too.

Comment: why don't u use database?

Comment: @codeit : Great question :) Because I want to use this to write a Rake task to populate a database actually. Something like my other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911323/looking-for-a-good-idea-and-a-good-ruby-structure/14911470#14911470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctors
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

Make sure you have `organization_id` like you wrote and then you can do (just as an example):

```
@doctor = Doctor.first
@doctor.organization

@organization = Organization.first
@organization.doctors
```

#### Update

Can't you populate the database with something like:

```
Doctor.where(name: "Frank", specialization: "Rubber Duck Surgery").first_or_create
```

Haven't tried this, but it's probably easier than looping through complex arrays:

```
@organization = Organization.where(name: "Surgeons").first_or_initialize
["Bob", "Frank", "Harry"].each do |name|
  @organization.doctors.where(name: name).first_or_initialize
end
@organization.save
```

#### Update

Ok, how about the following:

```
@doctor_names = ["Bob", "Rob", "Fred", "Bill"]
@doctor_salaries = [10000, 15000, 30000, 400]

def return_array_of_hashes(*data)
  array = []
  data[1].each_with_index do |d, i|
    hash = {}
    (0...data.count).to_a.in_groups_of(2).each do |a,b|
      hash.merge!({data[a] => data[b][i]})
    end
    array << hash
  end
  array
end

@doctors_array = return_array_of_hashes("name", @doctor_names, "salary", @doctor_salaries)
# => [{"name"=>"Bob", "salary"=>10000}, {"name"=>"Rob", "salary"=>15000}, {"name"=>"Fred", "salary"=>30000}, {"name"=>"Bill", "salary"=>400}]

@doctors_array.each do |hash|
  Doctor.where(hash).find_or_create
end
```

This way you could use the same method for any model you're creating and can easily add more data to the arrays. Just make sure you add the data in the correct order of `key` then `value`.

You might need to add a check that all arrays are of the same size, although your model validations will probably discard any invalid data.

Comment: nop, please see the comment and my answer to the comment under the question

Comment: Ah I see, not sure if it's what you're after but I've updated my answer.

Comment: Getting much closer :) That's what I had done initially but "they" said no! because they were like in future we don't want to go look for the methods and add more sample data to each method, we want them to be in some sort of structure at the top of the code, and methods just do the database population, so much less need to go into methods and populate data, instead modifying the data in the structure and methods loop through the structure and populate DB